# SSRS Add Parent Group to Entire Tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I've created a table for SSRS to show data for the current quarter, but end users now want to show previous quarters, when appropriate.  The request would be simple if it had been given from the start, as I just need to group all of my rows inside of a "Quarter" group.  But with the table already created and using multiple mixes of groups and blank rows, I can't figure out how to add Parent Group to the entire existing format.  Ideally, the solution would be through the Design view, but I'm thinking it will have to be done by modifying the underlying XML code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out by modifying the XML code.  I was wanting to add a Parent Row Group, so I found the `TablixRowHierarchy` tag and essentially mimicked the first `TablixMember` tag that contained a `Group` tag.  And wrapped all the existing `TablixMember` tags inside of a new `TablixMembers` tag.

I assume the same process would apply to column groups, just starting at `TablixColumnHierarchy` instead.

I ran into other issues, that appear to be limitations regarding the PageName attribute, as I want each Quarter on a different page, but that is unrelated to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the designer, right click on the outer most group and choose add parent group. Adding the group in the XML code is very messy, and not recommended. The added parent group can use a custom expression if needed.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the original groups were unrelated, (i.e. one group of two rows, then two ungrouped rows, then another separate group of two rows, etc...) so the Add Parent Group option would only encompass one group at a time.